# Смена алгоритма в вечернее время Spring java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Добрый день столкнулся с задачей. у меня есть ендпоинт, который отдаёт актуальные заказы на сегодняшней день, но повявилась потребность в том, чтобы после 6 вечера были видны заказы еще и на следующий.

Я вижу два варианта решения данной проблемы.

1. Каждый раз проверять время запроса и в зависимости от времени запроса вытаскивать еще и заказы на завтрашний день.
2. Я плохо знаком со Spring Schedule, но мне кажется, что с помощью его можно попробовать реализовать такой функционал.

Буду рад вашим предложениям.
Отдельная буду рад рабочим примерам.

Comment: Schedule - создает расписание для выполнения какой нибудь задачи, например выполнение синхронизации с удаленной БД в 6 вечера. В вашем случае логичнее проверять время запроса заказа и вытаскивать из базы нужные данные, согласно этому времени

Comment: Я тоже так думаю, но мне кажется при каждом запросе запрашивать LocalDateTime слишком тяжело будет? Я могу быть не прав. Я всего лишь советуюсь. =)

Comment: а зачем включать это в запрос? проверяете время в сервисе, а потом уже формируете запрос с интервалом времени для выборки заказов.